# can not find some pythonic way to pass symbolic attribute in a class

Tags: python, oop, attributes, sympy

Hope all are happy with your coding!
I need to make symbolic attribute for my class.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np    
class Sym_Class:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def sumsymbol(self):
        print(sum(sp.symbols("self.x") * sp.symbols("self.y")))   
ax = np.array(['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
by = np.array(['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])
cc1 = Sym_Class(ax, by)
cc1.sumsymbol()
```

while I got :
print(sum(sp.symbols("self.x") * sp.symbols("self.y")))
TypeError: 'Mul' object is not iterable
Could possibly let me know how can I do to get around this issue?

Comment: Don't mix `numpy`, `sympy` and custom classes before you have a good grasp of `sympy` itself.  The python `sum` expects an iterable, like a list.

Comment: If I put print(np.sum(sp.symbols("self.x") * sp.symbols("self.y"))) I will get: self.x*self.y, while  I need to get, .x1*y1+... to extract my fit equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because `sp.symbols("self.x")` creates one symbol, and `sp.symbols("self.y")` creates another symbol. Then, you multiply them to obtain a single symbolic expression, which is not iterable. The `sum` function requires an iterable.

As pointed out in the comments, try to avoid mixing numpy and sympy. For example, you could create lists for `ax` and `by`.

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np    
class Sym_Class:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # these attributes contains lists of symbols
        self.x = sp.symbols(x)
        self.y = sp.symbols(y)

    def sumsymbol(self):
        # use this syntax to perform the addition of products
        print(sum(u * v for u, v in zip(self.x, self.y)))   
ax = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
by = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
cc1 = Sym_Class(ax, by)
cc1.sumsymbol()
# out: x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3
```

Comment: That's right, Thank millions Davide_sd!